# Java Services SPI and Memory Leaks

Tags: java, singleton

I have 100s of services which I am currenly revamping/cleaning up so that they implementation complexity can be abstracted out. However, what I have noticed is that java SPI doesn't provision singleton-based SPI setup. Instead, it provides guideline for how to achieve this when SPI-based services are handled.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#singleton

the following code

`ServiceProvider sp = ServiceLoader.load(ProvierAPI.class).iterator().next()`

loads a new instance of `ServiceProvider` every time the `ServiceLoader` is queried. But I am not quite sure how it's ***not*** a memory safe operation since the following code will ensure a Garbage collection occurs after the context leaves the stack frame?

```
    public void doFoo() {

     ServiceProvider sp = ServiceLoader.load(ProvierAPI.class).iterator().next();

     sp.doServiceFoo();

     doSomethingElse();

     return;
}
```

Does using singletons "Truly" serve any benefit here? From what I understand, Singleton technically means a lot of permanent object references in memory (so called static `getInstance()` ).

Is it still better to use Singleton's for SPI related implementations?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO reducing the problem to the memory requirements misses important aspects.

```
ServiceLoader.load(ProvierAPI.class).iterator().next()
```

Each time this code runs the `ServiceLoader` has to find and read the provider configuration file(s), meaning that potentially all of the jar files on your classpath are inspected to check for provider configuration files.

That alone has some performance impact.

Another point is what the service providers do upon instantiation. If they are only creating a `Map` and filling it with a few values nothing bad will happen.

But consider the case of a dictionary service that reads a dictionary of several thousand words and their definitions from a file every time that service is instantiated. You certainly would prefer to do that once and not every time the user hovers the mouse cursor over some word in a `TextArea`.

---

In the end it very much depends on your service providers and how they are implemented.

Comment: "Each time this code runs the ServiceLoader has to find and read the provider configuration file(s), meaning that potentially all of the jar files on your classpath are inspected to check for provider configuration files" - I think you have some misunderstanding about SPI.

Comment: @ha9u63ar it seems that you never looked into the code behind `ServiceLoader.load()`. `ServiceLoader.load()`creates a new `ServiceLoader` object on each call and does a classpath scan each time.